# I have a data frame of char variables and I want to convert the df values to upper/lower case in r

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 6k plus rows and 10 variables. I want to convert the char variables to uppercase without changing the str of df.

Comment: Try `library(dplyr); df1 <- df %>% mutate_if(is.character, toupper)`

Comment: There's a discrepancy between title and question: does your data.frame contain only `character` variables (as in the title), or do you want only to convert the `character` variables (as in the question body)?

Answer (score 1):

```
df[sapply(df, is.character)] = toupper(df[sapply(df, is.character)])
```

---

### Explanation

We select only the columns containing characters with `sapply(df, is.character)`, then use the vectorized function `toupper` and reassign to the `data.frame`.